# Conditionally join to different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

We have two tables with identical schemas in two different databases. We have a job that runs and uses data that joins to one or the other of those two tables. What we would ideally like to do (which I know isn't possible) is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OtherData d
    IF (condition)
        INNER JOIN database1.Table t ON ...
    ELSE
        INNER JOIN database2.Table t ON ...
```

We tried building out a view that unions the two datasets and returns the condition as part of the view, so we could select where the condition is true. If we just select against the view, the query plan shows that it only hits the desired database without going to the other. If we join to the view though, it goes to both.

```
CREATE VIEW View_Table AS
    SELECT
        1 AS Condition,
        OtherData...
    FROM...
        database1.Table
    UNION
    SELECT
        2 AS Condition,
        OtherData...
    FROM
        database2.Table
GO


-- Then use it as:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OtherData d
    INNER JOIN View_Table vt ON vt.Condition = @Condition AND ...
```

So we are trying to figure out the best way (without just doing giant IF...ELSE... statements that duplicate large portions of our procs) to write this such that in execution we will only hit the desired database and not try to go to both when we know up front which to hit.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure to write your query with the IF/ELSE statement as put in your first example.

Comment: `select a.*  from tbl a
left join DB1.dbo.tbl1 b on a.col =b.col 
left join DB2.dbo.tbl1 c on a.col = c.col
`

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I tried putting it in a table-valued function that took the condition as a parameter, the problem is that I can't then limit it on other conditions until it has returned the entire dataset from the function unless I also pass those conditions in as parameters. Then I couldn't figure out what to join on in that case if everything is parameters.

Comment: Is this condition something varies per row or is it something scoped to the whole query?  IE: would row 1 get data from tableA and row 2 get data from tableB or would all the data come from one table or the other?

Comment: It seems like your view solves the problem.  It looks simple and effective from here. Haven't seen anything better in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISNULL` function:

```
SELECT      d.*,
            ISNULL(T1.Field, T2.Field) Field
FROM        OtherData d
LEFT JOIN   database1.[Table] t1
        ON  d.Field = t1.Field AND (condition)
LEFT JOIN   database2.[Table] t2
        ON  d.Field = t2.Field AND (condition)
```

Or the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT      d.*,    
            CASE    WHEN    (condition)
                    THEN    t1.Field
                    ELSE    t2.Field
            END Field
FROM        OtherData d
LEFT JOIN   database1.[Table] t1
        ON  d.Field = t1.Field
LEFT JOIN   database2.[Table] t2
        ON  d.Field = t2.Field
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a staging table to simplify your stored procedure.

Pseudosql...

```
truncate table stage.Table;

IF (condition)
    select * into stage.Table from database1.Table where ...
ELSE
    select * into stage.Table from database2.Table where ...

-- Then use it as:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OtherData d
    INNER JOIN stage.Table ON ...
```

IMHO, I'd try to do any type of data flow with SSIS packages which would also make it easier to conditionally hit different databases (via Control Flow).

Comment: I would use a temp table vice a staging table for this or you could end up with problems with race conditions. This also is only feasible if the tables involved are not so large (although you can index temp tables if need be).

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where dynamic SQL is probably your best bet.

And of course when telling people to use dynamic SQL, you must refer then to the page that describes the hazards of using it and how to protect your self when you must use it.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html